# What is this warped effect and how to achieve it?

Tags: reverse-engineering, effect, distortion

What is the name of the effect used in this photo and how do you apply it to a photo?

[image]

As you can see, the nearest servers (which look like cupboards) are somewhat distorted. That is the effect I want to know of.

Comment: -1. Stop asking and answering your own questions

Comment: @ClaraOnager The [SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) says, *..To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged..*** :D Try the **FAQ**

Comment: you're not doing this to help you're doing this to garner reputation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This effect is called **fisheye effect**

You can either get this effect by using a [fisheye lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens) or using photoshop. Try googling *fisheye effect photoshop*. I found there great tutorials there.

- http://www.marcofolio.net/photoshop/create_a_fish_eye_lens_effect_in_photoshop.html
- http://blog.lorrifreedman.com/index.php/2009/04/10/how-to-create-a-fisheye-lens-effect-using-photoshop/

Comment: To add to that: The effect is most 'natural' on wide-angle photos taken with 15mm and wider lenses.

Comment: You can also find more here http://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/fisheye/info and also on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens